# Python 3 dimensional fitting

Tags: python, data-fitting

I have a set of 3d data and would like to fit them with some polynomial ansatz in python. I can only find 2 dimensional solutions, could anyone provide me with some 3d solution? thanks!

Comment: Search the web for multidimensional polynomial ansatz instead of 3D. You'll find enough results :) Writing formulae too code is mostly not that hard.